# PHP : string number manipulation

Tags: php

I have a string like the following :

```
$number = '123456789012';
```

how to divide the string of numbers into the result :
1234 5678 9012

Comment: if only there was a php function for splitting strings

Comment: `var_dump(str_split(123456789012, 4));` https://3v4l.org/XurBm

Comment: chunk_split("123456789012", 4);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var_dump(trim(chunk_split('123456789012',4," ")));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try the followings

```
$number = '123456789012';

echo join(' ', str_split($number,4));
```